# Downloading snort rules

Tags: windows-server-2012, snort

I have downloaded snort rules from the website but instead of getting a zipped folder, I get a single file which cannot be opened by windows. I also tried using 7zip to extract the file regardless its a single file but it just replicates itself.

anyone know how I can resolve this or a get snort rules zipped folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a gunzipped tar ball (tar.gz) ([reference](http://www.gzip.org/)). You need to unzip it first, you can use 7-zip on windows just right click on it then > 7-zip > Open Archive. The archive will have a .tar file (community-rules.tar) just right click on this and hit Open. This should create a folder "community-rules" with a few files inside. The rules file is the one called "community.rules", all of the rules are in this file. If you open it with wordpad you should be able to see all of the rules.

If you're on linux/unix/mac you can just run the command:

```
tar xzvf community-rules.tar.gz
```

Comment: Hi, I am able to do as you said in the 7zip manager and it works fine. I cant seem to open the tar file outside the  7zip manager

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. If you follow those instructions you should be able to open it, it's just an archive nothing complicated... You need to extract the files out (or try dragging them and dropping them on your desktop?).